# Customizing a UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, user-interface

I'm wondering how I might go about customizing a UIActionSheet like this one:

When you press on the button to bring this view up, it does come up like a UIActionSheet but honestly I'm not quite sure that they aren't using some kind of custom animation with a UIView containing two buttons. Could anybody speak to how I might go about doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well for this you would have to make your custom `UIActionsheet` . You can do this by either making a `UIView` and bringing it up by animation (if you want to do no more and take an easy way out) or else you can consult this control also seeing that the interface you want to make is for iOS 7 :-
[UI7Kit](https://github.com/youknowone/UI7Kit)

This control includes all the UI7 control features that you can either add to your project or take an idea and build your own . Hope this helps !! :)

**EDIT :**

Well you could take a look at these links for making a custom `UIActionsheet`, they are tutorials like you mentioned..... please have a peek :-

https://www.altamiracorp.com/blog/employee-posts/display-a-custom-uiview-like-a

http://blog.corywiles.com/custom-uiactionsheet-using-core-animation

And there's this great control too using blocks !! :- [UIActionsheet With Blocks](https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets)

Comment: that's great advice. Could you point me towards a tutorial that goes over how to bring up a custom UIActionSheet? Thanks!

Comment: Upper link raise 403. About UI7Kit, code is slightly verbose because it is patching original UIActionSheet. But only a method is important. (See link) You should call this method after showing your action sheet. https://github.com/youknowone/UI7Kit/blob/master/UI7Kit/UI7ActionSheet.m#L47