# UIActionSheet with Images like menu

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactionsheet

How I can create something like this:

[image]

Because `UIActionSheet` has only text

```
- (NSInteger)addButtonWithTitle:(NSString *)title;
```

Comment: You need to create a custom UIView. Please, see this topic http://stackoverflow.com/a/17938953/1993465 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a UIActivityViewController

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

If you require more than what it provides, you'll need to create your own UIView